# MySQL: mysqld in cmd returns "Can't change dir to..."

Tags: mysql

I've just joined to ask for help regarding this.

Whenever I type mysqld in CMD I get the following:

```
mysqld: Can't change dir to 'c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS
errno 2 - No such file or directory)
2018-08-12T09:16:41.903311Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] c:\Program Files\MyS
QL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.12) starting as process 2740
2018-08-12T09:16:41.965711Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test f
ile c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\Moonwilles-PC.lower-test
2018-08-12T09:16:41.965711Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test f
ile c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\Moonwilles-PC.lower-test
2018-08-12T09:16:41.965711Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010172] [Server] failed to set datadir
 to c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\
2018-08-12T09:16:41.965711Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-08-12T09:16:41.965711Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] c:\Program Files\MyS
QL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.12)  MySQL Com
munity Server - GPL.
```

I've looked literally everywhere, I installed MySQL using the MySQL installer on 3 different computers, I got the same problem on all of them. This is the most ridiculous and frustrating thing I've ever encountered.

The MySQL service is on.
I tried typing mysqld --initialize and it seems to have made things worse as whenever I type 'mysqld' CMD now 'freezes' momentarily before actually executing the command.
The 'my.ini' file is setup correctly.
The data directory is in 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data'.

I've forgotten my root password and I am trying to recover it. I followed the guide found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html and it's not even working.
I cannot log in to phpMyAdmin anymore.

Comment: Data and data are recognised as two different places! first try to change it to data!

Comment: 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' and 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\'  are two different places

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Yes, I am aware of that, but why the error?
Why is it looking in the Program Files? How do I change it?